# Is there a rather complete definition of a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, class, object

People...

Here is my problem.  I am converting a legacy system to PHP, HTML5, JavaScript etc etc.  The old system was an old asp system.  I know a lot has to be changed and the languages are anything but compatible.  However I need to keep the "base logic" the same.  This means I need a class in JavaScript.  Below is the stripped down class (object?) I have created.  I have looked all over and cannot determine how to call the initStuff module from the "constructor" or from the resetStuff function.  Any Help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Charlie

```
  var Person = function () {
  var _isMyFriend;
  var _myFriendsName;
  //HOW DO I ACCESS INIT STUFF FROM HERE
  };     //<=======SHOULD THIS BE MOVED TO THE END OF THE FUNCTION?

  Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hi " + _myFriendsName);
  };

  Person.prototype.setName = function(passedName) {
    _myFriendsName = passedName;
  };

   Person.prototype.initStuff = function() {
    _myFriendsName = "unknown";
    _isMyFriend = false;
  };

   Person.prototype.resetStuff = function() {
  //HOW DO I ACCESS INITSTUFF FROM HERE?
   };
```

Comment: If you're writing JavaScript like VB, you're doing it wrong.  Better to learn proper JavaScript idioms like module pattern.

Comment: There is no destructors in JS, as there is no in Java.

Comment: Indeed.  "Most unfortunately for you," these are *entirely(!)* different languages.  They really take an entirely different (and therefore, largely incompatible ...) perspective on the problem. such that *there is no* "bright-line rule primrose-path" from one to the other.  So, what you're dealing with here is what's euphemistically called "an impedance mismatch."  There *is no* "one-to-one correspondence" of any kind between "what you can tell VB" and "what you can tell JS."

Comment: Javascript ES5 and before does not actually have a `class` concept.  It has a `prototype` concept which can be used to solve similar problems, but has different implementation, different strengths and different weaknesses.  Javascript ES6 adds the `class` keyword, but it's really just syntax sugar over the `prototype` concept and works like prototypes, not like classes in other languages.  As others have said, if you try to emulate another language in Javascript, you will end up with somewhat smelly Javascript as the languages just aren't the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind responses.  I just need to create a class in javascript.  I can (for instance) google Java Person Class and get many responses, (same for VB) however when I do the same for javascript there are giant lectures on inheritance and what not, I know about classes I thought this would be an easy.  I am not trying to emulate VB I just want to instantiate an object and then in a method reinstantiate the object by calling the instantiate function.  I do believe in all the programming rules and I won't be able to sleep tonight if I ever wrote the same routine twice

Comment: OK, I rewrote the question to better explain the problem.  I am not trying to do a line for line translation of VBScript to JS I am writing a new program.  In order to not have to change the logic of the program I need to use a class or object.  I am having trouble calling a one of the functions from another function germane to the class.

Comment: @CharlieElliot Js is prototype based, not class based, you will have to deal with it...

Comment: I am dealing with it.  One can search for JavaScript Class on this site as well as others and find a plethora of discussion about classes.  So you are simply WRONG (it may be a prototype based language BUT one can simulate classes).  If you are not going to help me then don't waste my time with remarks that are not true.  My grandmother used to say "Empty tin cans make the most noise."  So I am dealing with it.  I need help in calling that function.  If you cannot help me deal with it kindly find something else to do.

Comment: @CharlieElliot I just meant that you have to "deal with it" as in "proceed with necessary adjustments" - didn't mean to offend nor to tell you it´s impossible to adapt from vb. But then again, no one here is going to give you a course about basic javascript, which is essentially what you're asking for.

Comment: I´m going to answer one of your concerns, however. From the prototype methods you cannot access private members of the initial object declaration. Translation: from `resetStuff`, you cannot access `_isMyFriend`. 2 options to work this around: 1. create a getter for each private member (quite standard imho) or 2. instead of using `var _isMyFriend = ...` use `this._isMyFriend = ...` so the variable becomes a property and therefore, public. Then from `resetStuff` you would only need to use `this._isMyFriend` since `this`, used within the prototype members, refers to the "super" object.